# web scraping python multiple attributes in line (div and id)

Tags: python, html, class, web-scraping, attributes

I would like to webscrape [this](http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/brazil/copa-do-brasil/results/#/) page.
 So, I started with this script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

links = {"Copa do Brasil": "http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/brazil/copa-do- 
brasil/results/"}

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'}

data = []
for club, link in links.items():
    response = requests.get(link, headers = headers) 
    #print(response.status_code) #200 is OK

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    #print(soup.prettify())  #to check if soup downloads correctly. 
    table = soup.find_all('div', attrs ={'id', 'tournamentTable'})
    print(table)
```

The problem is in the following lines when inspecting the html code:

```
<div id="tournamentTable" style = "display: block;">
   <table class =" table-main" id="tournamentTable"> </table> ==$0
```

I am wondering, what I should do, to get the table of all matches. I got stuck in the fact that class, id and style are used together.

Answer (score 1):

try the read html from pandas

```
    import pandas as pd



    i = 0

    for line in your_html_response_from_requests:
        try:
            i = i+1
            df = pd.read_html(your_html_response_from_requests.content)[i]      
            df.to_csv(file,header=False, index=False,sep=';',encoding='utf-8')
        except Exception as err:
            break
    file.close()
```

i used the to_csv to create the file, but you can use anything

Comment: Well that give back 2 columns with 5 lines:
    
    0  Nations League  Internationals
    1  Premier League          LaLiga
    2         Serie A         Ligue 1
    3      Bundesliga     ATP US Open
    4     WTA US Open            WNBA
    5             MLB             NFL

While i'm looking for the table with the results of the copa do brasil matches.

Comment: i can't test the site itself to see where  the mistake was done beacause of a paywall in the site itself. if you provide the HTML with the right data you wanna scrape maybe i can fix the issue in the code

Comment: Not sure if you mean this (since I'm a bit of a newbie in this). This is the html?
    <html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"xml:lang = "cs" > ==$0 
I try to scrape the data of the matches (teams, score, infobutton and odds)

Comment: yeah, you need an account to access the link, try downloading the html and then editing the post with just the part you need to scrape